# Issue with setting a game object active

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have been working on a game recently, and I have written the sell function. I've got game objects that I have animated and want to have float up when the user hits the 'sell' button. The animation happens when the game object first becomes active, which is why I am using the `.SetActive()` function. However, it runs the rest of the function fine but not the `.SetActive()` block.

Here is the function:

```
public void Sell()
    {
        
        plusOneImage.SetActive(true);

        //increase score
        ScoreManager.instance.AddToScore(InventoryManager.instance.GetNumberOfGold() * GameManager.instance.goldWorth);
        ScoreManager.instance.AddToScore(InventoryManager.instance.GetNumberOfSilver() * GameManager.instance.silverWorth);
        ScoreManager.instance.AddToScore(InventoryManager.instance.GetNumberOfRubies() * GameManager.instance.rubyWorth);
        ScoreManager.instance.AddToScore(InventoryManager.instance.GetNumberOfEmerald() * GameManager.instance.emeraldWorth);
        ScoreManager.instance.AddToScore(InventoryManager.instance.GetNumberOfDiamonds() * GameManager.instance.diamondWorth);
        ScoreManager.instance.AddToScore(InventoryManager.instance.GetNumberOfLapis() * GameManager.instance.lapisWorth);

        //reset values
        InventoryManager.instance.ResetGold();
        InventoryManager.instance.ResetSilver();
        InventoryManager.instance.ResetRuby();
        InventoryManager.instance.ResetEmeralds();
        InventoryManager.instance.ResetDiamonds();
        InventoryManager.instance.ResetLapis();

        
    }
```

What I tried was having it as a seperate function, calling it in different places within the function, making the `GameObject` a prefab, and probably one or two other things that I'm forgetting. I'm open to ideas of What I could try, I have hit quite the wall working on this.

Comment: The provided code snippet is insufficient to reach an answer. Given the rest of the method is executed, then `plusOneImage.SetActive(true);` is executed, too. The issue should be originating from some place elsewhere.

Comment: @Dimitar, the only other time I call anything with the `plusOneImage.SetActive(true)` is when I define that GameObject as `public GameObject plusOneImage;`. Other than that it is not touched at all during the rest of the code

Comment: What do you mean by define? You declare the parameter, but set in the Unity Editor, right? Maybe the game object is indeed set active, but there is a different cause. 

After pressing the button, and calling `Sell()`, is the Image gameObject activated in the Editor? In the Inspector tab, on the top left near the name of the game object there is a tick for that.

Comment: Yes, the game object still shows as Active in the inspector. And my apologies for the incorrect terminology there, I set the parameter but assigned it a value in the Unity Editor. It's been puzzling me, and my other thought was to do it from a different script but I wanted to see if I could figure this out before I did that

Comment: If the game object is active, then the lack of animation must be due to some other reason. For example, make sure the object is initially deactivated (check mark in the Editor must be off).